# Numerical Solution of giant Analytic DE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have a little bit of a problem regarding numerical solutions.
I have a system of two entirely symbolic differential equations of two functions, F[r] and K[r]. One of them is fairly simple, but the other is a monster with second and first order derivatives raised to powers, under square roots, multiplied by powers of r and so on. DSolve is currently trying to find a solution, but judging from the equation it won't be able to (and I didn't expect so).

The first equation is:

```
(-2 + 2 F[r] - r^2 (F^[Prime][Prime])[r])/(2 r^2) - ( 3 r Derivative[1][F][r] Derivative[1][K][r] + 2 F[r] (Derivative[1][K][r] + r (K^[Prime][Prime])[r]))/(2 r) == 0
```

and the second one:

```
(F[r] (-Derivative[1][K][r] + K[r] (H^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r]))/(
r K[r]) + 1/8 k (-(4/B) - (2 k λ^4)/(r^2 K[r] (2 r^6 Λ F[r]^2 K[r]^3 + 
      2 r^5 F[r]^2 K[r]^3 Derivative[1][F][r] + 
      4 r^5 F[r]^3 K[r]^2 Derivative[1][K][r] - 
      3 r^6 F[r]^2 K[r]^2 Derivative[1][F][r] Derivative[1][K][
        r] - r^6 F[r]^2 K[r]^3 (F^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r] - 
      2 r^6 F[r]^3 K[r]^2 (K^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r] + Sqrt[
      r^4 F[r]^2 K[
        r]^2 (k^2 λ^4 + 
         r^6 F[r]^2 K[
           r]^2 (3 r Derivative[1][F][r] Derivative[1][K][r] + 
            K[r] (-2 Derivative[1][F][r] + 
               r (-2 Λ + (F^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r])) + 
            F[r] (-4 Derivative[1][K][r] + 
               2 r (K^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r]))^2)])) - (
 2 (2 r^6 Λ F[r]^2 K[r]^3 + 
    2 r^5 F[r]^2 K[r]^3 Derivative[1][F][r] + 
    4 r^5 F[r]^3 K[r]^2 Derivative[1][K][r] - 
    3 r^6 F[r]^2 K[r]^2 Derivative[1][F][r] Derivative[1][K][r] - 
    r^6 F[r]^2 K[r]^3 (F^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r] - 
    2 r^6 F[r]^3 K[r]^2 (K^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r] + Sqrt[
    r^4 F[r]^2 K[
      r]^2 (k^2 λ^4 + 

       r^6 F[r]^2 K[
         r]^2 (3 r Derivative[1][F][r] Derivative[1][K][r] + 
          K[r] (-2 Derivative[1][F][r] + 
             r (-2 Λ + (F^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r])) + 
          F[r] (-4 Derivative[1][K][r] + 
             2 r (K^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r]))^2)]))/(
 k r^6 F[r]^2 K[r]^3) + (
 4 (2 r^6 Λ F[r]^2 K[r]^3 + 
    2 r^5 F[r]^2 K[r]^3 Derivative[1][F][r] + 
    4 r^5 F[r]^3 K[r]^2 Derivative[1][K][r] - 
    3 r^6 F[r]^2 K[r]^2 Derivative[1][F][r] Derivative[1][K][r] - 
    r^6 F[r]^2 K[r]^3 (F^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r] - 
    2 r^6 F[r]^3 K[r]^2 (K^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r] + Sqrt[
    r^4 F[r]^2 K[
      r]^2 (k^2 λ^4 + 
       r^6 F[r]^2 K[
         r]^2 (3 r Derivative[1][F][r] Derivative[1][K][r] + 
          K[r] (-2 Derivative[1][F][r] + 
             r (-2 Λ + (F^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r])) + 
          F[r] (-4 Derivative[1][K][r] + 
             2 r (K^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r]))^2)])^2)/(
 B k^2 r^4 λ^4 F[r]^2 K[r]^2)) == 0
```

My question is:
How do i make a numerical method for this particular problem? These function were set as general ones, and the whole purpose is to determine their form. The obvious next step is numerical methods, but for example i dont know what range to set in NDSolve. 
How would you approach this problem? Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S. The subject is General Relativity, and the solutions i'm searching for are black hole solutions, if that helps at all.

Comment: It does not help at all until you show us the equations (preferably in Mathematica format) :/
We want to copy paste your problem to our notebook to find its solution.

Comment: You don't give us any code or expressions, so obviously we can only give vague suggestions. `NDSolve`, or perhaps even better `ParametricNDSolve` if you want to play around with different values of parameters, should be your first port of call. The underlying physical problem should give you an idea of a reasonable integration range for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, here is one of the equations:
(-2 + 2 F[r] - r^2 (F^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r])/(2 r^2) - (
  3 r Derivative[1][F][r] Derivative[1][K][r] + 
   2 F[r] (Derivative[1][K][r] + r (K^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r]))/(2 r) == 
 0
Unforunatelly, the second equation is too big to fit here. The rest of the code is just the working towards these equations.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I have properly edited  the question (i am a newbie in thie site, please be patient!). I think I might actually try to test explicit forms of function according to the physical problem, but I would like to hear what you think still. Thank you again!

Comment: It looks to me that the expressions for 2nd derivatives became corrupt when you converted them from standard form to input form for pasting in you question. `F^[Prime][Prime]` should be `Derivative[2][F][r]` and similarly for 2nd derivative of `K`.

Comment: Do you have boundary or initial conditions?  What is the range of `r`?  What are the parameter values?  These are all needed for `NDSolve`.

Comment: Well, I'm looking for black hole solutions so I'm expecting r to go from zero up to what we'd call "a long way outside the event horizon radius (some multiple of the radious)", with an infinity popping up at zero. In order to do that though I'm guessing i'll have to give the functions a general form and then get a parametric solution. (the last step will introduce another equation with one additional parameter so the problem will still be solvable)